# inputrc vi keys, ipython and the del key

Tags: bash, ipython, readline

I have the following `.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command

set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set completion-ignore-case on
```

In bash when I type following (in insert mode!) as an example,

```
# cat ~/.vimrc
```

and then press the `Home/Pos1` key and then the `Del` key the result is the following:

```
# at ~/.vimrc
```

So far so expected. Now, for `ipython`. I type:

```
In [1]: from bla import blub
```

and then press the `Home/Pos1` key and then the `Del` key the result is

```
In [1]: From bla import blub
```

the cursor is at the position of the `r` and it is not in insert mode anymore which is not what vim would do, right (not even in `compatible mode`)?

Any ideas?

I understand my workflow is not exactly vim-style but I am just very used to it sshing to non-vi keys environments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related. Perhaps ask this on [vi.stackexchange.com](http://vi.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Agreed. http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6121/inputrc-vi-keys-ipython-and-the-del-key

Comment: @DevSolar  I've closed the vi.SE one as off-topic as it's not vi-related, but a GNU readline and/or ipython problem. This question seems [on-topic for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "software tools commonly used by programmers". ipython seems to fit that bill.